# Is Raspbian Wheezy Compatible with the Pi Zero?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy, raspbian-jessie, pi-zero

I heard from Adafruit that "Raspbian Wheezy does not have the updated firmware for this much RAM" in regards to the Pi Zero. This doesn't make any sense to me, seeing as I run Wheezy on my Pi 2, which has more RAM. They also said that Raspbian Jessie is the only Raspbian compatible with the Pi Zero. Is this true?

Comment: You are correct, it does not make sense since the firmware is maintained independently of Raspbian; it is also simple enough to update yourself.  It may apply to some old images.

Comment: :| well, if I update from wheezy to jessie will it make any substantial changes that could cause problems?

Comment: You should update unless you are aware of a reason not to.  Jessie is now the current stable version.  Major difference is it uses systemd instead of SysV init.

Comment: @goldilocks In the process of upgrading now, is there any way to disable to default boot to desktop setting via the command line?

Comment: I think `systemd set-default multi-user.target` should work.  Let me know if it doesn't and I'll have a look at a clean image.

Comment: Can you post the link ? From where exactly you read that ?

Comment: @PatrickCook - you can also use `sudo raspi-config` which is just a curses version of the graphical Raspberry Pi Configuration utility. Go to "Boot Options" and select whatever you like (e.g. Console or Console Autologin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last official Raspbian Wheezy image was 2015-05-07 and official images moved to Jessie afterwards. This was 5 months before the Zero was released, so didn't contain the firmware for the Zero or the pi-3 for that matter.

This can be fixed by booting them in an older pi, 
then running

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

The SD card will then boot fine in a Pi Zero / Pi 3

I did exactly that and have uploaded the image here for Pi Zero and pi3 users:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspbian-wheezy-pi/